# Handle deep nested complex xml with FreeMarker

Tags: java, freemarker

This is a part of a complex xml template which i put here for the question :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document>
    <CstmrDrctDbtInitn>
        <GrpHdr>
            <MsgId>${MsgId}</MsgId>
            <CreDtTm>${CreDtTm}</CreDtTm>
            <NbOfTxs>${NbOfTxs}</NbOfTxs>
            <a> ${val1}
              <b>
                ${val2}
              </b>
            </a>
            <CtrlSum>${CtrlSum}</CtrlSum>
        </GrpHdr>
        <PmtInf>
            <PmtInfId>${PmtInfId}</PmtInfId>
            <PmtMtd>${PmtMtd}</PmtMtd>
        </PmtInf>
        <#list persons as person>
        </#list>    
    </CstmrDrctDbtInitn>
</Document>
```

I have been using [FreeMarker](https://freemarker.apache.org/) for the previous month and until now the xml models have been easy

Searching over the web on how to approach this template , should i create matching java classes (100 of them ? )... should i use Map? like shown [here](http://zetcode.com/java/freemarker/) .

I don't have a clue how to do it ... how to apply FreeMarker on this template ?

Comment: Where does the data coming from? In what format?

Comment: @ddekany I found an answer below :)

Comment: @ddekany  The format is xml , the data is created by us . Consider all the data as String . You are right i missed adding these info :)

Comment: If you have lot of data in a certain format, you don't have to re-wrap it into hand-made classes. Instead write some generic code that converts them to nested `Map`-s/`List`-s, and pass that to the template. Or, since the data is XML, you can directly expose it to template as W3C DOM, since FreeMarker knows how to access that. Last not least, you can extend `DefaultObjectWrapper` and do whatever magic is needed to expose (even load on demand) your data to templates.

Comment: @ddekany Excellent thank you sooo much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is a solution for any future users . Firstly i created 3 models which i am calling like below :

```
    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();


    //================= Example Creating HeaderVo //=================

    HeaderVo header = new HeaderVo("la","la",5,5,"la","la");
    data.put("header", header);

    //================= Example Creating MiddleVo //=================

    MiddleVo middleVo = new MiddleVo("la","la",5,"la","la","la","la");
    data.put("middle", middleVo);

    //================= Example Creating internal items =================


    InternalVo v1 = new InternalVo(5, 5, 5, "s", true, "zz", "zzzz", "ll","EUR");
    InternalVo v2 = new InternalVo(5, 5, 5, "s", true, "zz", "zzzz", "ll","DOLLARS");
    InternalVo v3 = new InternalVo(5, 5, 5, "s", true, "zz", "zzzz", "ll","LAT");


    //List parsing 
    List<InternalVo> internalVos = new ArrayList<>();
    internalVos.add(v1);
    internalVos.add(v2);
    internalVos.add(v3);
    data.put("vos", internalVos);

    //================= //=================  //=================   //================= 


    final String message = this.templateManager.composeStringFromTemplate(data, "bankfile.ftl");
```

So below is the `bankfile.ftl` which represents the complex xml :

```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02">
    <CstmrDrctDbtInitn>
        <GrpHdr>
           <MsgId>${header.msgId}</MsgId>
           <CreDtTm>${header.creDtTm}</CreDtTm>
           <NbOfTxs>${header.nbOfTxs}</NbOfTxs>
           <CtrlSum>${header.ctrlSum}</CtrlSum>
           <InitgPty>
            <Nm>${header.nm}</Nm>
            <Id>
                <OrgId>
                    <Othr>
                        <Id>${header.id}</Id>
                    </Othr>
                </OrgId>
            </Id>
           </InitgPty>
        </GrpHdr>
        <PmtInf>
           <PmtTpInf>
            <SvcLvl>
                <Cd>${middle.svcLvlCD}</Cd>
            </SvcLvl>
            <LclInstrm>
                <Cd>${middle.lclInstrmCD}</Cd>
            </LclInstrm>
            <SeqTp>${middle.seqTp}</SeqTp>
           </PmtTpInf>
           <ReqdColltnDt>${middle.reqdColltnDt}</ReqdColltnDt>
           <Cdtr>
            <Nm>${middle.nm}</Nm>
           </Cdtr>
           <CdtrAcct>
            <Id>
                <IBAN>${middle.iBAN}</IBAN>
            </Id>
           </CdtrAcct>
           <CdtrAgt>
            <FinInstnId>
                <BIC>${middle.bIC}</BIC>
            </FinInstnId>
           </CdtrAgt>           
           <#list vos as vo>       
           <DrctDbtTxInf> <PmtId> <EndToEndId>${vo.endToEndId}</EndToEndId> </PmtId> <InstdAmt Ccy="${vo.ccy}">${vo.instdAmt}</InstdAmt> <DrctDbtTx> <MndtRltdInf> <MndtId>${vo.mndtId}</MndtId> <DtOfSgntr>${vo.dtOfSgntr}</DtOfSgntr> <AmdmntInd>${vo.amdmntInd?c}</AmdmntInd> </MndtRltdInf> </DrctDbtTx> <DbtrAgt> <FinInstnId> <BIC>${vo.bIC}</BIC> </FinInstnId> </DbtrAgt> <Dbtr> <Nm>${vo.nm}</Nm> </Dbtr> <DbtrAcct> <Id> <IBAN>${vo.iBAN}</IBAN> </Id> </DbtrAcct> </DrctDbtTxInf>
           </#list>
        </PmtInf>
    </CstmrDrctDbtInitn>
</Document>
```

```

And finally here are the 3 models used for the FTL ( sorry for them being huge , i just wanted to so how complex it can get :) ):

`HeaderVo`

```
public class HeaderVo {


    private String msgId;
    private String creDtTm;
    private int nbOfTxs;
    private int ctrlSum;
    private String nm;
    private String id;


    public HeaderVo() {
        super();
    }


    public HeaderVo(String msgId, String creDtTm, int nbOfTxs, int ctrlSum, String nm, String id) {
        super();
        this.msgId = msgId;
        this.creDtTm = creDtTm;
        this.nbOfTxs = nbOfTxs;
        this.ctrlSum = ctrlSum;
        this.nm = nm;
        this.id = id;
    }




    public String getMsgId() {
        return msgId;
    }


    public void setMsgId(String msgId) {
        this.msgId = msgId;
    }


    public String getCreDtTm() {
        return creDtTm;
    }


    public void setCreDtTm(String creDtTm) {
        this.creDtTm = creDtTm;
    }


    public int getNbOfTxs() {
        return nbOfTxs;
    }


    public void setNbOfTxs(int nbOfTxs) {
        this.nbOfTxs = nbOfTxs;
    }


    public int getCtrlSum() {
        return ctrlSum;
    }


    public void setCtrlSum(int ctrlSum) {
        this.ctrlSum = ctrlSum;
    }


    public String getNm() {
        return nm;
    }


    public void setNm(String nm) {
        this.nm = nm;
    }


    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


}
```

---

`MiddleVo`

```
public class MiddleVo {

    private String svcLvlCD;
    private String lclInstrmCD;
    private int seqTp;
    private String reqdColltnDt;
    private String nm;
    private String iBAN;
    private String bIC;

    public MiddleVo() {
        super();

    }

    public MiddleVo(String svcLvlCD, String lclInstrmCD, int seqTp, String reqdColltnDt, String nm, String iBAN,
            String bIC) {
        super();
        this.svcLvlCD = svcLvlCD;
        this.lclInstrmCD = lclInstrmCD;
        this.seqTp = seqTp;
        this.reqdColltnDt = reqdColltnDt;
        this.nm = nm;
        this.iBAN = iBAN;
        this.bIC = bIC;
    }

    public String getSvcLvlCD() {
        return svcLvlCD;
    }

    public void setSvcLvlCD(String svcLvlCD) {
        this.svcLvlCD = svcLvlCD;
    }

    public String getLclInstrmCD() {
        return lclInstrmCD;
    }

    public void setLclInstrmCD(String lclInstrmCD) {
        this.lclInstrmCD = lclInstrmCD;
    }

    public int getSeqTp() {
        return seqTp;
    }

    public void setSeqTp(int seqTp) {
        this.seqTp = seqTp;
    }

    public String getReqdColltnDt() {
        return reqdColltnDt;
    }

    public void setReqdColltnDt(String reqdColltnDt) {
        this.reqdColltnDt = reqdColltnDt;
    }

    public String getNm() {
        return nm;
    }

    public void setNm(String nm) {
        this.nm = nm;
    }

    public String getiBAN() {
        return iBAN;
    }

    public void setiBAN(String iBAN) {
        this.iBAN = iBAN;
    }

    public String getbIC() {
        return bIC;
    }

    public void setbIC(String bIC) {
        this.bIC = bIC;
    }

}
```

---

`InternalVo`

```
public class InternalVo {

    private int endToEndId;
    private int instdAmt;
    private int mndtId;
    private String dtOfSgntr;
    private boolean amdmntInd;
    private String bIC;
    private String nm;
    private String iBAN;
    private String ccy;


    public InternalVo() {
        super();
    }



    public InternalVo(int endToEndId, int instdAmt, int mndtId, String dtOfSgntr, boolean amdmntInd, String bIC, String nm,
            String iBAN,String ccy) {
        super();
        this.endToEndId = endToEndId;
        this.instdAmt = instdAmt;
        this.mndtId = mndtId;
        this.dtOfSgntr = dtOfSgntr;
        this.amdmntInd = amdmntInd;
        this.bIC = bIC;
        this.nm = nm;
        this.iBAN = iBAN;
        this.ccy = ccy;
    }



    public int getEndToEndId() {
        return endToEndId;
    }

    public void setEndToEndId(int endToEndId) {
        this.endToEndId = endToEndId;
    }

    public int getInstdAmt() {
        return instdAmt;
    }

    public void setInstdAmt(int instdAmt) {
        this.instdAmt = instdAmt;
    }

    public int getMndtId() {
        return mndtId;
    }

    public void setMndtId(int mndtId) {
        this.mndtId = mndtId;
    }

    public String getDtOfSgntr() {
        return dtOfSgntr;
    }

    public void setDtOfSgntr(String dtOfSgntr) {
        this.dtOfSgntr = dtOfSgntr;
    }

    public boolean isAmdmntInd() {
        return amdmntInd;
    }

    public void setAmdmntInd(boolean amdmntInd) {
        this.amdmntInd = amdmntInd;
    }

    public String getbIC() {
        return bIC;
    }

    public void setbIC(String bIC) {
        this.bIC = bIC;
    }

    public String getNm() {
        return nm;
    }

    public void setNm(String nm) {
        this.nm = nm;
    }

    public String getiBAN() {
        return iBAN;
    }

    public void setiBAN(String iBAN) {
        this.iBAN = iBAN;
    }

    public String getCcy() {
        return ccy;
    }



    public void setCcy(String ccy) {
        this.ccy = ccy;
    }
```